# jQuery data() from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set jQuery object's data using a function:

```
oTabSearch.data('search_data', collect_data());
```

Is there a way to somehow recalculate this data piece e.g. if I get data from object:

```
var search_data = oTabSearch.data('search_data');
```

it would first set 'search_data' data using `collect_data()` function and then return it?

Comment: Do you mean, do both lines in one line, or every time you request `.data('search_data')` it runs `collect_data`

Comment: No, pls read http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Just to clarify what you are asking, do you want the "search_data" data item to be calculated on-the-fly whenever it is requested?

Comment: I don't get it, does'nt it already do this ? -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WpNNC/), and what would be the point of storing something in data, if the function runs and the data is recalculated everytime, would'nt it be easier to just run the function directly?

Comment: adeneo,
This approach allow me to assign different search criteria to each tab so that I can get data for search in one place and specific way like this:
$(this).data('callback')($(this).data('search_data')());

I set the data in one place and if something will change I can easily edit the data settings in one place. This is very convenient approach in my opinion. Do you have any better ideas of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this...

```
oTabSearch.data('search_data', collect_data);  // notice no parenthesis
```

and to run the function...

```
var search_data = oTabSearch.data('search_data')();  // notice the empty parenthesis
```

That effectively stores a copy of the function as a data object and then runs it again when you request.  It does not store any return value.

Here's an example jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/Tr3zK/

Click "mydiv" to see the data value, therefore calling the function again.

Comment: I rejected the edit because it was exactly the same as my suggestion, but you passed an anonymous function into data, rather than a function name.  Other than that it was exactly the same thing.  Glad you got it working :)